# to find which button was clicked out of a list of buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

**problem**

I am creating an application that takes care of all the contact details of a person. The records are stored in a text file such that the 5th index to the 10th index consist of the nick name of each contact as given by the user. I want to give a list of all these nick names as buttons and when the user selects any one button then the details of this contact will be shown using `tkSimpleDialog.showinfo('text','contact details')`.

---

**goal**

1. to decide which button was clicked in a list of buttons.
2. this is a problem that I am facing often: to pass a parameter to a callback function

---

**code**

Note that this code does not accomplish what I want to implement.

```
buttons = []

inFile = open('test','r')

for i in inFile:

    thisrecord = i    
    buttons.append(Button(self.frame,text='Name: %s' %i[5:10],command=self.show(thisrecord))

inFile.close()
```

---

**what I tried**

When I tried the above code then what happenned was that the last record stored in the file was shown each time, whatever button I press. And I found out why this happenning. Apparently the buttons are all created at one time and then the callback function is called whenever each button is called.

In case I had a limited number of buttons, then I could definitely define functions for each one of the buttons and then use them as callback. This is what I am doing in the welcome page of my application that has buttons like: `add new contact` and `see details of contact` and so on.

But in this case the number of records are not fixed. So I am in a fix here and dont understand what to do.

I further tried using check buttons, so that whichever records that the user wants to see, he can tick and press proceed and go on. But even this failed as again the checkbuttons are first created and not while the code runs through there.

**please** help me with this issue.

---

**specs**

Linux Mint 14 
Python 2.7
tkinter 8.5

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen a similar question at least twice in the last couple of weeks, but couldn't succeed in searching for them :(

Comment: The behavior you described does not match the snippet you exhibit. The behavior of your code is to actually execute callbacks as buttons are created and do not perform any action when button are then clicked.

Comment: Yea. The behaviour that I explained was what I wanted to accomplish. And the code did not accomplish it. I will edit the question to this effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed, you call `self.show(thisrecord)` before a button can even be created, as this is part of the buttons arguments. You want to have a function as a callback instead.

So to fix it make a functions that returns a function that can be used as a callback:

```
# add to your class
def showCallback(self,record):
    """ returns a callback for self.show """
    def callback():                 # make a new function
        return self.show(record)    # that shows the given record
    return callback                 # return this function

for thisrecord in inFile:
    buttons.append(Button(self.frame,text='Name: %s' %i[5:10],
                           command=self.showCallback(thisrecord))
```

`self.showCallback(thisrecord)` will return a different function for each record now.

Comment: A really elegant solution! Thank you so much! And I have been thinking why I did not think of this!!

Answer (score 3):

In your example `self.show(thisrecord)` is executed when creating the Button and the result (probably None) bound to `command`.

What you want is to pass a function here that is executed when you click the button, not at construction time. One way of doing that would be to use `functools.partial`, like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

root = tk.Tk()
buttons = []
inFile = ['... line1 ...', '... line2 ...', '...']

def show(par):
    print par

for i in inFile:
    thisrecord = i    
    button = tk.Button(root, text='Name: %s' %i[5:10], command=partial(show, thisrecord))
    button.pack()
    buttons.append(button)

tk.mainloop()
```

Or you can define your own function which returns a callback function that will do the work.

*note*: when posting an example it's always good to include everything necessary to just paste it into an interpreter to make run it...

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing by: `command=self.show(thisrecord)` is that you are actually executing the function `self.show(..)` with the parameter `thisrecord` and assigning the return value to the key `command`.

What you should actually be doing:

```
command=partial(self.show, thisrecord)
```

what [**`partial`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) does is returns a new function with a frozen portion of parameters.

---

Another example to demonstrate `partial`:

```
from functools import partial

def fn(x):
    print x

functions = []
for i in range(0,3):
    functions.append(partial(fn, i))

for func in functions:
    func()
```